# Hide custom taxonomy posts from Recent posts

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have some custom taxonomy in my WordPress site, but I want to hide a custom taxonomy post from my Recent posts. I have this code:

```
    $c1 = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'quality',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 123,
    ))
    );
     $c2 = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post__not_in' => $c1,
            'posts_per_page' => 10, 
             );
    $recent = new WP_Query($c2);  
    while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work. How should I do this?